# "Offensive" vs. "Insulting"

Tags: word-usage, adjectives, word-difference

What situations are more suitable for each of these adjectives?

> 1. Insulting
> 2. Offensive

Are they similar in what they imply, or is "insulting" much stronger?

Comment: We are getting dangerously close to The Semantic Zone.

Comment: A question like this one should really include some dictionary references provided by the O.P. (Please see paragraph 3 "Show Your Research" in [this meta post](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please) for more information on that.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Offensive" is pretty much something people identify as against morals, very inappropriate, or disrespectful.

e.g.

> Alex posted very offensive comments on other peoples' Facebook pages. They included several racial slurs.
>
> That horror movie was deemed very offensive by many.
>
> If you think the content of this video is offensive, leave now.

"Insulting" is something rude, insensitive and/or offensive, directed at another person or group of people. **This emphasizes that the content is a direct attack against specific others.**

> Jamie said very insulting words to Ken, and that hurt his feelings a lot.
>
> He wrote an insulting letter to the committee after he vehemently disagreed with their decision.

Comment: You have to have something between "the content" and "this video".